# How do I get an Amazon book to Amazon Kindle on my Lenovo tablet without a WiFi connection

Tags: kindle

I can’t get the WiFi connection between my WiFi router to my Lenovo tablet to work. I can connect the tablet to the computer with USB, so how would I get a book I’ve ordered on Amazon with the computer to load into my tablet?

I guess I need to either:
Connect the Kindle app on my Lenovo tablet with the USB cable connection to the Internet, passing through the computer.

Or
Download the book to the computer then copy the file someplace on the Lenovo tablet.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) to move the book from your PC to your tablet over USB.  Calibre is by far the most powerful ebook management software.

However, the *real* issue is why your tablet wont connect to WiFi.  If your tablet is Android based, then you should ask on [android.stackexchange.com](https://android.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Calibre is very much a great answer to the question.